# Installing ImageMagick Onto Xampp/Windows 7

Tags: php, apache, dll, xampp, imagick

ImageMagick is working when I test it from cmd but when using it for Xampp and restarting it then the error message I receive is:httpd.exe-Entry Point Not Found. The procedure entry point MagickGetImageGravity could not be located in the dynamic link library CORE_RL_wand_.dll.

The second message is PHP StartUp: Unable to load dynamic library C:\xampp\php\ext\php_imagick.dll- The specified procedure could not be Found.

I'm pretty sure second error message is caused by first error up top. Probably wrong dll. I'm on Windows 7 64 BIT running PHP 5.3.5 and Apache 2.2.17. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

My refrence is this [page](http://valokuva.org/?p=197)

ImageMagick 6.8.0 binaries compiled with VC9 (Visual Studio 2008). I noticed that the official ImageMagick builds are now Visual Studio 2010 and that wouldn’t work well with PHP compiled with 2008. see phpInfo() and search for **compiler** and **php version**.

The download link for the binaries is here: [imagick-php54-php53.tgz](http://valokuva.org/~mikko/imagick-php54-php53.tgz)

I download this folder and copy php54 -> php_imagick_ts.dll to xampp\php\ext

My PhP Version is : ***PHP Version 5.4.4***

then rename it to php_imagick.dll. 
At the end restart your appache server.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem and banged my head against all kinds of possible solutions before finally finding a combination of Imagick builds and dll's that would play nicely with my setup. Here's what finally worked for me:

- OS: Windows 7 64 Bit
- PHP: 5.5.6
- XAMPP: 1.8.3

  - Compiler: MSVC11
  - Architecture: x86
- ImageMagick: ImageMagick-6.7.7-5-Q16-windows-dll (available [here](http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/packages/ImageMagick/binaries/))
- Imagick DLL: PHP5.5.x version from  http://www.peewit.fr/imagick/

Once I finally had this set up, Apache finally started without any errors. Hopefully it works for you, too!

Answer (score 0):

I think there some problem loading imagemagick php module while you install latest version of windows binary ,i rectify the problem by download 6.7.7-5-Q16 32bit version and its worked on that version.once install this version download imagemagick PHP module and restart apache.