# How to install ImageMagick to use with PHP on Windows 7 (3)

Tags: php, windows, windows-7, imagemagick, imagick

There are other threads about how to install Imagick on Windows 7 but no help for me so far. (Maybe problems have came up with more recent versions)

I have followed these steps to install:

1. Download and install ImageMagick

> http://www.imagemagick.org/download/binaries/ImageMagick-6.8.8-1-Q16-x86-dll.exe

2. Download php_imagick.dll and copy to extension dir (c:\xampp\php\ext)

> http://www.peewit.fr/imagick/php55/vc11/x86/ts/php_imagick.dll

3. Edit php.ini file and add new extension (c:\xampp\php\php.ini)

> extension=php_imagick.dll

4. Save ini file and restart Apache (if necessary, restart Windows)
5. Start Apache and run test

When I start Apache i get a pop up box that displays:

> The program can't start because php5.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

Then directly after this comes another:

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_imagick.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

[According to funtioneer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036847/how-to-install-imagemagick-on-windows-7) I suspect some kind of compilation error.

Now I have PHP Version 5.5.6 (xampp 1.8.3) with compiler MSVC11 which is the same as for the php_imagick.dll file.

Is download ImageMagick from source and compile it on my own the right way to go? (have never compiled in Windows before)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Instead of using the latest version I tried downloading ImageMagick-6.7.7-5-Q16-windows-dll from [here](http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/packages/ImageMagick/binaries/). That one actually worked with the php_imagick.dll (Imagick for PHP 5.5.x) from http://www.peewit.fr/imagick/.

This is not the latest version but it worked. (even without restarting the computer)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the older versions and the advice to downgrade.  This was an absolute crapshoot for me.  Just in case anyone else is trying to do this, I was able to get everything working using the ImageMagick-6.7.0-10-Q16-windows-dll.exe from the ftp.sunset.se link.  I'm using Apache and PHP 5.3.x on Windows 7.  No Windows restart required, but I did restart Apache

Comment: It works. I downloaded the imagick dll from http://www.peewit.fr/imagick/ and kept a note of the ImageMagick version with which it was tested. Then I downloaded the particular version from http://ftp.sunet.se/pub/multimedia/graphics/ImageMagick/binaries/

Comment: I've been looking for v6.5.5.*-windows-dll for a while. Normal sites seem to have removed them. However, I finall got one from google code. For those who have suffered not finding them, the link is: http://code.google.com/p/rimagebook/downloads/detail?name=ImageMagick-6.5.9-9-Q16-windows-dll.exe&can=2&q=

Comment: God bless you @embe!!! I lost the better part of the day trying to setup imagick on my Windows 7 machine. The current version now is 6.9.0-8, along with imagick 3.1.2, php 5.5/5.6. I tried dozens of tuts but your is finally working for me!

Comment: I can confirm that this works for windows 10 too, make sure to downgrade your php version to 5.5.x

Comment: Working.  It's best to use the version of imagemagick which the wrapper/plugin was tested with.  The wrappers seem to get out of date pretty fast since imagemagick is quite actively developed in comparison.

Comment: You are a saviour! I was trying to install since 4 hours and finally it's working now. It is working fine in Windows 10.

Answer (score 10):

Here what finally worked for me after trying almost every possible solution posted in internet:

Environment:

```
OS: Windows Server 2008 R2 (64bit)

IIS: 7.5

PHP: 5.5.11 (x86)

PHP.ini: VC11, x86
```

[Download](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows) and install ImageMagick

```
ImageMagick-6.8.9-1-Q16-x86-dll.exe
```

[Download](https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/deps/) corresponding .zip from Anatol suggested sources (kudos to Anatol!)

```
ImageMagick-6.8.9-1-vc11-x86:
```

Extract to a temporary folder and copy the contents of the "bin" folder inside the Imagemagick installation `(c:\imagemagick)` in my case overwriting files.

Download `.dll` and put it in the php extensions folder
(I used this one)

Imagick for PHP 5.5.x Non Thread Safe from:
http://www.peewit.fr/imagick/

Add the extension to php.ini with:

```
extension=php_imagick.dll
```

Save php.ini and restart IIS

Finally Image Magick information was displayed in a phpinfo(); call.

It is incredible to think to solve this problem needed to download files from 3 different locations.

Hope it helps.

Comment: worked perfectly for me:
OS: Windows 8.1 (64bit)
PHP: 5.5.11
I downloaded `ImageMagick-6.8.9-1-Q16-x86-dll.exe` from [sunet.se](http://ftp.sunet.se/pub/multimedia/graphics/ImageMagick/binaries/) because the latest stable version of ImageMagick 6.8.9.6. showed [this error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457744/installing-imagemagick-onto-xampp-windows-7)

Comment: @davey got it from [http://www.peewit.fr/imagick/](http://www.peewit.fr/imagick/)

Comment: Worked! Xampp Win7 x64

Comment: As the question was about XAMPP which of course is Apache and not IIS maybe you should amend that piece of your answer.

Comment: Worked for me with Win10 using WAMP PHP 5.5 x86 TS

Answer (score 7):

Here is what I did to get it working
Note: The step that really tripped me up that didn't really explain is that the php_imagick.dll version should match your install of imagick

Ok so steps I taken was
download php imagick dll from 
http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/3.1.2/ (I used php_imagick-3.1.2-5.5-ts-vc11-x86.zip)

The zip file will contain many dlls keep this in mind, we may need it in future.
Extract php_imagick.dll to your extension folder

Put that in extension folder

IN php.ini add 
extension = php_imagick.dll

Now the issue is we need to find out what version of imagick the php_imagick.dll was compiled for
Open command prompt and type in php -e -v
The way I did this was with the zip you downloaded earlier, extract the other DLLs to your php folder an error message will probably popup stating something about missing dlls. So extract the DLLs from the zip folder from before into your PHP folder.
Try running php -e -v again and it should work fine with no error message.
If that is the case then
Restart apache. Now look at phpinfo() and go to the imagick section. It will say ImageMagick version:  Mine said ImageMagick 6.8.6-8  which is an older version then they have on their site. The issue is that ImageMagick number of supported formats: will probably say zero.

Go [here](http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/packages/ImageMagick/binaries/) and download the matching version and install (when you install make sure the checkbox of adding to path variable is checked)

Once finish installing Stop apache. Delete the DLLS from the php folder that you put in earlier and start apache again. Check 
restart apache and it should all work.

Comment: I've tried to get this working for a long time. The crucial part for me was copying the additional DLL files into the php folder!

Answer (score 3):

The ImageMagic distribution which should be used is from here http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/deps/ . The ImageMagic binaries need to be built with the same CRT as the PHP extension is.

Comment: How do you know which CRT the PHP extension is?

Answer (score 3):

Please see [installing-imagick-php-7](http://herbmiller.me/2016/06/16/installing-imagick-php-7/) for installing imagick php extension on Windows using php 7.0 +.  It's only real solution I have found so far.  It goes into great detail.

Comment: I confirm. This seems to be the only way to do it for now. The other solutions don't exactly work. Make sure to set `MAGICK_HOME` and add the same path to `PATH` or you'll get `Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library './ext/php_imagick.dll' - The specified module could not be found. in Unknown on line 0`!

Comment: Heads-up: I had to move the content of my path\ImageMagick\bin to path\ImageMagick folder before the php_imagick.dll file could recognize the libary using phpinfo().

Answer (score 2):

## UPDATED: 21.08.2017

I got worked ImageMagick with php 7 and IIS (Apache very similar):
Imagick **Version. 3.4.3**

> PHP 7 nts x86, Windows Server 2012 x64, IIS 8.5

1) Install VC++ 2015
https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=48145

2) Get **ONLY**  `php_imagick.dll` from https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick

3) Put it into php/ext/ folder and add `extension=php_imagick.dll` to `php.ini`

**Attention!**
Minimum versions supported PHP >= 5.4.0 and ImageMagick >= 6.5.3-10.

**ImageMagick  7 are not supported at this time.**

Look at phpinfo:

[image]

You must install ImageMagick 6.9.3-7 Q16 x86 
4) install `ImageMagick 6.9.3-7 Q16 x86 dll`
from http://ftp.icm.edu.pl/packages/ImageMagick/binaries/
Do not uncheck "add variable to path".

5) restart server

thats all

Comment: You do not need the whole VC++ 2013, All you need is the runtime libraries [from here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784) You also need to add this `extension=php_imagick.dll` to your `php.ini` file. A reboot is not necessary, all you need to do is restart Apache.

Comment: Yes i mean only libraries and provide link for it. And i use IIS8.

Comment: But the person asking the question uses XAMPP which means they use Apache.

Answer (score 0):

It works by following steps.

`php 5.5 32bit ts`+`apache 2.4`+`windows 10 64bit`+`Imagick 6.9.3-5`+`php_imagick.dll ts`

Check what's bit of your system bit.

Choose a `php_imagick.dll` version from 
http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/

Find `php_imagick.dll` from `.zip` file

If you don't know how to choose.

Type `php -v` get php version at commandline window

Run following code shows which kind of php you have installed,`thread safe` or `non thread safe`.and click [here](http://www.usingscript.com/how-to-know-if-the-installed-php-is-thread-safe-ts-or-non-thread-safe-nts/) will help you.

On windows:`php -i|find "Thread"`

On Linux:`php -i|grep Thread`

or you can run function `phpinfo()` and search `"Thread"` on web page.

You will see `Thread Safety enabled` or `Thread Safety  disabled`

Other steps have already been written out by @embe.

Answer (score 0):

Now for something the documentation does not mention: setting the MAGICK_HOME value in your environment. ImageMagick requires this variable so it knows where to find all relevant coders.

Open up the control pannel, and search for 'PATH'. In the results, select 'Edit the system environment variables'. Select the 'Environment variables...' option, and add a new 'System variable' (the lower list). If you've chosen a different installation path, make sure to replace C:\img with your own path.

Variable: MAGICK_HOME

Value: C:\img\modules\coders

[see more](http://refreshless.com/blog/imagick-pecl-imagemagick-windows/)

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

After having the same problems and some googling I found the solution for windows, and it seems to work for every release as well.

In my case PHP is installed at c:\php and my extension dir is at c:\php\ext.

1. Copy "php_imagick*" into **c:\php\ext**
2. Copy "CORE_RL_*", "FILTER_*", "IM_MOD_*" into **c:\php**
3. Add "extension=imagick" to php.ini

Restart apache and your done.

Comment: I can confirm it works, but mixing files from one library with the main php directory is a bad idea in the long run