# Trouble installing ImageMagick for PHP on Windows

Tags: php, imagemagick, wampserver

I'm trying to learn ImageMagick for PHP, so it made sense for me to install it on local machine. I'm running a Windows 8 x64 system, running WAMP 2.5 with Apache 2.4.9 and PHP 5.5.12.

I found instructions here: http://refreshless.com/blog/imagick-pecl-imagemagick-windows/ and followed them, but no luck. I got the latest copy of ImageMagick 6.8.9 from the ImageMagick website. When I run the tests provided on the site, ImageMagick responds fine. However, PHP doesn't show ImageMagick as installed in `phpinfo()`.

I'm not sure what else to do. I've restarted my PC twice, I've installed everything twice, tried the DLL form difference resources. I'm at a loss for how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

So turns out, the latest version isn't always the way to go. I found this: [How to install ImageMagick to use with PHP on Windows 7 (3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20976779/how-to-install-imagemagick-on-windows-7-3), the first answer. The dll site listed detailed the version tested; I installed that version of ImageMagick, and it looks like its working now.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting confused:

Imagemagick just needs to be installed from the Imagemagick download and it will work in php with exec() Make sure you allow the install to write imagemagick path to the environment? as Windows has a built in convert command as well.

This will not show up in php.ini as it is an external program.

The pecl file with the dll is Imagick which is a API for php and can be a pain to install.
This will show up in the php.ini file - you need to uncomment it in the the php.ini file to get it to hopefully work.

You need to confirm which you want to use Imagemagick or Imagick.