# PDF Image thumbnail preview in laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, preview, laravel-5.1

I have file module, where I want to list all files,with thumbnail preview.

as like follows,

[image]

I am storing files in `storage` folder,which is not accessible via `http`.

So How can I provide thumbnail preview for docs especially image and PDF.

Is there any package availabe in laravel 5.1?

Comment: You may not find a Laravel-specific answer, but there's plenty of PHP answers to this. See [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/467793/how-do-i-convert-a-pdf-document-to-a-preview-image-in-php) for example.

Comment: but getting very difficulty to install and make work `imagick` on windows..

Comment: Hmm, my first reaction is that you shouldn't be running PHP on Windows! But I know imagemagick can run on Windows. I googled for you; here's one result I found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20976779/how-to-install-imagemagick-to-use-with-php-on-windows-7-3. But in any case, the question I linked above also includes answers that don't require imagemagick.

Answer (score 11):

The preview image of a PDF file is usually the **first page** of the PDF file.

You can use [ImageMagick](https://www.php.net/imagick) to obtain that first page of the PDF file.

```
<?php
$imagick = new imagick('sample.pdf[0]'); // 0 specifies the first page of the pdf

$imagick->setImageFormat('jpg'); // set the format of the output image
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); // set the header for the browser to understand
echo $imagick; // display the image
?>
```

You can also output (save the contents of the image in a file) and store it under a thumbnail folder with the PDF name as the file name. like ( sample.jpg )

As for a solution based on laravel, I don't think laravel has any package that can do the same

Answer (score 1):

Though the question was posted quite a long ago but I'm answering because it might helps others. There is a package for generating image from pdf. [Pdf to Image](https://github.com/spatie/pdf-to-image). You should have [Imagick](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.setresolution.php) and [Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/) installed