# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: imagick: Unable to initialize module

Tags: php, windows, dll, version, imagick

I have read similar issues but I believe that the solution to mine might be new:

I have recently upgraded my Windows 10 to PHP 8.2.1, and today I added `extension=ext/php_imagick` to **php.ini**, and when running `php -v` I get the following error:

```
Warning: PHP Startup: imagick: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20210902
PHP    compiled with module API=20220829
These options need to match
```

I have tried downgrading to PHP 8.1, but the module API version was still more recent, plus I have been downloading Imagick from sources that said it was compatible with PHP 8.2...

I have tried installing the latest version of Imagick from various sources, following [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20976779/how-to-install-imagemagick-to-use-with-php-on-windows-7-3), but I keep getting the error.

Thinking that there might not be yet an official packaged version of Imagick compiled with the latest module API, I have been following [this guide](https://imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php#windows) to compile Imagick by myself, I have put the **bin** folder URL into the Path, relaunched the command prompt and this time received the error:

```
the procedure entry point MagickSetSeed could not be located
```

That was my whole day, I am out of ideas...

Comment: After downgrading to PHP 8.0.27:
`Module compiled with module API=20190902` and `PHP compiled with module API=20200930`

Comment: I solved my issue by downgrading to PHP 8.1 and using [this version of Imagick](https://mlocati.github.io/articles/php-windows-imagick.html), but I shouldn't put this as the accepted solution because it's really just a workaround and not an actual solution

Comment: Possible the imagick can work until PHP 8.1?
My local is PHP 8.2 which totally cannot use at all

Answer (score 3):

There is no official release of imagick for PHP 8.1+ in windows

However, this is an unofficial build in an open Github issue thread.

https://github.com/Imagick/imagick/issues/573#issuecomment-1431773928

https://github.com/Imagick/imagick/issues/573#issuecomment-1578638424

Note: Try at your own risk, it's not guaranteed that it will work